# Can you manifest Bestow Power on yourself, your Schism mind, or your Fission Duplicate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

You are a valid target of Bestow Power as you are "one psionic creature"

> You link your mind with another psionic creature’s mind, creating a
> brief conduit through which mental energy can be shared. When you
> manifest this power, the subject gains up to 2 power points. You can
> transfer only as many power points to a subject as it has manifester
> levels.

One could argue the first sentence is just fluff and the real effect description starts on the second sentence. On the other hand one could argue the opposite and say the text is not italicized therefore not fluff therefore valid targets that are not another psionic creature's mind make the power fail.

**Schism** is a separate mind as you. However is the Schism a "another psionic creature's mind"?

1. The Schism is not a "another psionic creature" despite schism being another psionic mind and the power likens you to two characters sharing one body. Multi-headed monsters are not treated as separate creatures for each head. So if the power is specifically asking for another creature, the answer is no.
2. On the other hand, the power is asking for another MIND and the Schism is most definitely a separate MIND than you. So if the power is asking for another "psionic creature's mind" then the answer is yes because Schism, while not a separate creature, is a separate mind. The schism is a "psionic creature's mind".
3. Schism is your mind, not another creature's mind. It is another mind but not another creature's mind. So the answer is no.

**Fission** is definitely a separate psionic creature and mind as you. However

> You cannot use fusion or metaconcert with a duplicate, or share any
> other power or effect that pools abilities (the sum of you and you is
> still just you). Similarly, attempting to use powers such as claws of
> the vampire or vampiric blade to hurt your duplicate only damages your
> duplicate; these powers do not heal you. Empathic transfer and similar
> powers are likewise ineffective (transferring wounds to yourself isn’t
> a good healing strategy).

Does the above exclude Bestow Power?